# In React-native, how to make multiline of more than one text?

Tags: react-native

I have something like this

```
<View>
  <Text>By clicking this I accept </Text>
  <TouchableHighlight>
    <Text>Terms and Conditions, </Text>
  </TouchableHighlight>
  <TouchableHighlight>
    <Text>Privacy Policy</Text>
  </TouchableHighlight>
</View>
```

and it looks like this

```
By clicking this I accept 
Terms and Conditions
Privacy Policy
```

or if I have it in a row it looks like this (`|` shows border of the screen)

```
|                                        |          
| By clicking this I accept Terms and Con|ditions, Privacy Policy
|                                        |
```

and I want it to look like

```
|                                       | 
| By clicking this I accept Terms and   |
| Conditions, Privacy Policy            |
```

By that I mean, that if a word doesn't fit on the screen, it is put in a next row. Just like a multiline text but with multiple texts and touchable highlights. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 7):

Try something like this.

```
<Text>
    <Text>By clicking this I accept </Text>
    <Text onPress={() => console.log('terms pressed')} style={{color: 'red'}}>Terms and Conditions</Text>
    <Text>,</Text>
    <Text onPress={() => console.log('privacy pressed')} style={{color: 'red'}}>Privacy Policy</Text>
</Text>
```

Just replace the console.log with a reference to whatever function you wish to handle the click.

Comment: It does work, but only with `flex: 1` in style of the outer text (any positive number works). Could you edit the answer? I will then mark it as correct.

Comment: That all depends on what you wish the text container to do. Flex 1 isn't saying "I want this to be full width". Flex is relative to other components at the same level of the layout. If you had two lots of the above code in a View with flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' and you add flex: 1 to the outer Text you will end up with 2 lots of the above text, each taking up 50% of the width of the screen but still with the wrapping behaviour. Basically flex: 1 is not always required depending on your layout. It would be misleading to others to put it in the answer. These comments should clarify it.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't even think that putting `Text` inside of `Text` would work

Answer (score 2):

You could style it:

```
flexWrap: 'wrap',
flexDirection: 'row',
```

Comment: this one is fine. (I used it as style for wrapper View with Text child)

Answer (score 1):

```
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");
<View style={{width:width}}>
//your code
</View>
```

Comment: Please explain more.

Comment: setting width with respect to screenwidth brings the text to new line if it goes off the screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
<View style={styles.termsContainer}>
                                <Text style={styles.term_service}>By signing up you accepted our </Text>
                                <Text onPress={() => navigation.navigate("TermsAndConditions")}
                                    style={styles.terms_text}>Terms of Service </Text>
                                <Text style={styles.term_service}>and </Text>
                                <Text onPress={() => navigation.navigate("TermsAndConditions")}
                                    style={styles.terms_text}>Privacy Policy </Text>
                            </View>


termsContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    marginLeft: Dimens.margin_normal,
    marginRight: Dimens.margin_normal
},
term_service: {
    color: Colors.black
},
terms_text: {
    color: Colors.primary
}
```

[image]